# Select conditional in C #, it is not visible

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote this SQL statement, then my SQL server was running.

```
SELECT r.RentID,c.CustomerName,v.VehicleName,r.[Hours], r.[Hours] * v.Rent AS Total FROM Rent as r 
INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN Vehicle AS v ON r.VehicleID = v.VehicleID
```

Also when I write in C #, it does not display, although some SQL statements such as Add, Update, Delete are running normally.
I want to ask where I'm wrong and how to fix it. Thank you very much.

```
public IList getRents()
{
    IList result = new List();
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon);
        String query = "SELECT r.RentID,c.CustomerName,v.VehicleName,r.[Hours], r.[Hours] * v.Rent AS Total FROM Rent as r INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID INNER JOIN Vehicle AS v ON r.VehicleID = v.VehicleID";
        //String query = "SELECT * FROM Rent";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Rent r = new Rent();
            r.rentID = (int)reader[0];
            r.customerID = (int)reader[1];
            r.vehicleID = (int)reader[2];
            r.hours = (int)reader[3];
            //r.total = (int)reader[4];
            result.Add(r);
        }
    con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what does "it doesn't display" mean

Comment: At least you are trying to cast CustomerName, VehicleName to int.

Comment: Please learn to use the debugger and do something more useful with exceptions than `ex.ToString()` and you will quickly find out what's going wrong.

Comment: I totally agree with @Filburt. Your catch is actually worse than not doing anything. You have effectively hidden any error. This is an anti-pattern I call try/squelch. You went to the trouble of catching the error but then you tossed in the trash can and continued as though nothing happened.

Comment: @SeanLange I like that.  "try/squelch".  I'm gonna use this in the future, thanks!

Comment: @SeanLange nice. It reminds me of the old Visual Basic `On Error Goto Next` which ignored anything that went wrong and was tough to debug.

Comment: also, as to "it doesn't display" and outside of any SQL errors. What are you doing with the list that is returned?

Comment: @fabulous lordy, I can't believe that code construct is real.

Comment: @Amy - believe it or not, it is. Before .NET, (and I think it's still there for backward compatibility) error handling wasn't done by `Try...Catch` blocks in VB. It required labels at the end of your method so it was common to have a label called `Handler:` and just before it to exit out of the method. The first line would then be, `On Error Goto Handler` so that it would jump there. You could then retry the same code if you fixed it, or load some default and go to the next line. Speaking of which, I realized I made a mistake in that post. `On Error Resume Next` is the way it was done.

Comment: Yeah I remember the old VB days and the On Error nonsense. Ugh!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to map the SQL column `CustomerName`, which is likely a `VARCHAR` or string-compatible type of some kind, to an `int`.

```
Rent r = new Rent();
r.rentID = (int)reader[0];
r.customerID = (int)reader[1];  // here's your problem: reader[1] is CustomerName
r.vehicleID = (int)reader[2];
r.hours = (int)reader[3];
//r.total = (int)reader[4];
result.Add(r);
```

How you resolve it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you want `CustomerName` and not `CustomerId`, you'll need to add a property called CustomerName with type `string` to your `Rent` model and update your reader:

```
Rent r = new Rent();
r.rentID = (int)reader[0];
r.customerName = (string)reader[1];  // updated
r.vehicleID = (int)reader[2];
r.hours = (int)reader[3];
//r.total = (int)reader[4];
result.Add(r);
```

If you want `CustomerId`, then you need to change your SQL:

```
SELECT r.RentID, c.CustomerId, v.VehicleName, r.[Hours], r.[Hours] * v.Rent AS Total FROM Rent as r INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID INNER JOIN Vehicle AS v ON r.VehicleID = v.VehicleID
```

---

## More Information

There are some issues with your code that prevented you from debugging what was wrong.

First, you're catching any exceptions that can possibly be thrown and swallowing them up. `getRents()` will always successfully return, but if there's any errors at all, it'll return an empty `List` and you'll never know why. My guess is that's why you're saying "it doesn't display".

For the purposes of debugging, remove the `try catch` block. You can add it later but only do so if you're planning on doing something with the exception, such as displaying friendly error messages and/or logging them.

When you run your code without the `try catch` block, it will throw an exception that should help you figure out what was wrong.

There are some other issues as well. It's generally a good idea to utilize `using` statements on objects that implement `IDisposable`. A quick and easy way to determine if they do is to initialize it, then see if there's a `.Dispose` method:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.Dispose();
```

If `conn.Dispose()` doesn't have a compiler error, or Intellisense shows it as a valid method, then the object is disposable and you should use a `using` statement:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    // ...
}
```

Disposing disposable objects helps to prevent memory leaks and free up resources you no longer need. Further, it lets you do stuff like this:

```
public IList getRents()
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(sCon))
    {
        var query = "SELECT r.RentID,c.CustomerName,v.VehicleName,r.[Hours], r.[Hours] * v.Rent AS Total FROM Rent as r INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID INNER JOIN Vehicle AS v ON r.VehicleID = v.VehicleID";

        using (var com = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader())
            {

                IList result = new List<Rent>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Rent r = new Rent();
                    r.rentID = (int)reader[0];
                    r.customerID = (int)reader[1];
                    r.vehicleID = (int)reader[2];
                    r.hours = (int)reader[3];
                    //r.total = (int)reader[4];
                    result.Add(r);
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I refactored your method a bit to be easier to read and debug. Note that `return` is being called right after the `SqlDataReader` completes instead of at the very end of the method. This enables you to keep variables closer to where they're being used, in this case `result`. This makes it easier to find potential problems and correct exceptions that do come up.

Finally, since `getRents` really only does mapping from SQL to C# objects, I think a micro-ORM like Dapper will help you greatly. This is more of a personal decision but if you're app is doing a lot of CRUD work, then an micro-ORM like Dapper would cut down considerably on the time it takes to write as well as lower potential problems.

Consider this refactored version using Dapper:

```
public IList GetRents()
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(sCon))
    {
        var query = "SELECT r.RentID,c.CustomerName,v.VehicleName,r.[Hours], r.[Hours] * v.Rent AS Total FROM Rent as r INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID INNER JOIN Vehicle AS v ON r.VehicleID = v.VehicleID";
        return conn.Query<Rent>(sql).ToList();
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a lot shorter, simpler, and straight to the point. Just make sure your class properties match your SQL column names. Stack Overflow uses Dapper; in fact, they developed it. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you verry much

Answer (score 1):

You are casting everything to int. Clarify if you want the name or the ID in your code. If you want the ID then change your query to read

```
String query = "SELECT r.RentID,c.CustomerID,v.VehicleID,r.[Hours], r.[Hours] * v.Rent AS Total FROM Rent as r INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID INNER JOIN Vehicle AS v ON r.VehicleID = v.VehicleID";
```

If it was the names you wanted then change the respective fields to cast to a string. Also check the data type produced by multiplying `r.Hours * v.Rent` as this could be rounding your results inadvertently for the line you commented out.

You never specified the exception you are getting. It's possible it fails because your are casting strings (the 2 names) to an integer. As it is, your code swallows any exception and doesn't report it or log it so finding the exact source of the problem won't be to easy.

Consider this in your exception handler

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

then check your Output window for what error you got. And place it here so we can better help.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to know the query in C # I have a problem. Although it runs very well in SQL Server

Comment: If you want the query in C# you'll need to look into LINQ though I that's not where your problem is in this case. In any case, whether the query works or not, you cannot find out because of your exception handler so it's not clear if this is the query or trying to read from it. Make the necessary changes to the exception handler and things will become clearer as to what is going on.

Comment: Now, I see. Thank you verry much

Answer (score -3):

Try it.
In your code you had a "*" the most

```
public IList getRents()
{
IList result = new List();
try
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon);
String query = "SELECT r.RentID,c.CustomerName,v.VehicleName,r.[Hours], r.[Hours] , v.Rent AS Total FROM Rent as r INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID INNER JOIN Vehicle AS v ON r.VehicleID = v.VehicleID";
//String query = "SELECT * FROM Rent";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
Rent r = new Rent();
r.rentID = (int)reader[0];
r.customerID = (int)reader[1];
r.vehicleID = (int)reader[2];
r.hours = (int)reader[3];
//r.total = (int)reader[4];
result.Add(r);
}
con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
ex.ToString();
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: The star was used to multiply [Hours] by [Rent], I doubt that is causing the problem. In your code, [Hours] occurs twice in your select.